# Why do characteristic functions use $e^{ix}$ and not $e^{-ix}$? Does it matter?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I've heard the characteristic function be described as the Fourier-Stieltjes Transform of the distribution measure of a r.v., but I was curious as to why it's written as $E[e^{ix}]$ and not the typical $E[e^{-ix}]$ that I'm used to seeing.

Is there a purpose or is it just difference in notation?

Comment: The way I heard it, the difference is just stylistic and usually engineers use one, and mathematicians use the other, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You save on writing the minus sign a bunch of times. Mathematically, you could put a minus there and it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think it reflects the fact that even for the Fourier transform there is no clear convention.. Some use $e^{ix}$, other $e^{-ix}$ or $e^{2i\pi x}$

you can read more about it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions)

The main properties are of course the same, there is going to be a difference however in the actual calculations